# Dual columns where one is justified and the other is ragged right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ragged2e

I am writing a report on the differences between justified- and ragged right alignment. I am trying to demonstrate the differences between them by having two columns next to each other (multicols). How would I do to make them have different alignments, without affecting the whole document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With two minipages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.475\textwidth}
\lipsum[4]
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.475\textwidth}
\raggedright
\lipsum[4]
\end{minipage}
\bigskip

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\sometext{You are my sunshine, my only sunshine, you make
  me happy when skies are gray, you'll never know dear, how much I
  love you, please don't take my sunshine away}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{%
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}% ragged right
%  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}% ragged on both sides
%  >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{5cm}% ragged left
  p{5cm}% justified
  }
  \sometext & \sometext
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```